# variables of type double comparison always returns false

Tags: c++

my code has something like this:

```
double TMR_HV ;
....
TMR_HV =2.0; // in another part of my code


void RTKAPI Tempos10(void * p) // task for timers
{
    while(1) {
        if (TMR_HV > 0.00)  TMR_HV -= 0.01; 
        else TMR_HV = 0.00;
        RTKDelay(1);
    }
}
```

The condition `if` is always false. can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The variable, as seen in the posted code, is not initialized. Is it initialized somewhere else? If not, its value can be anything.

Comment: Perhaps TMR_HV is NaN or +Inf

Comment: the variable is global and it´s initialized at 0.0, and when we place a break point on the timer, the initial value is 0.0 and it runs has expected. when the variable get a value bigger then 0.0 it starts to decrease and never stop. it goes to negative values.

Answer (score 0):

It is important that you declare your TMR_HV variable not inside other function. It should be global.

Comment: Yes, it´s a global variable and it´s declared like this: double TMR_HV = 0.0;

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem this way. 
I create this function

```
int DblComp(double A, double B)
{
    LONG32 aL;
    LONG32 bL;
    aL = (LONG32) ( A * 1000.0);
    bL = (LONG32) ( B * 1000.0);
    if (aL < bL) return (-1);
    else if (aL == bL) return (0);
    else return (1);
}
```

then when I need compare 2 double variables I call this function

```
if (DblComp(ReadWriteDisk_C, 0.00) == MAIOR)
        ReadWriteDisk_C -= 0.01;
else ReadWriteDisk_C = 0.00;
```

the Maior is defined as 1